# Почему не работает overflow-x у таблицы, если у родителя display: flex;?

Tags: css, flexbox, таблицы

коллеги.
Прошу помочь справиться с проблемой.
САБЖ: 
Есть несколько оберток, которые задают сетку сайта. 
Внутри main нужна таблица, которая при сужении экрана должна иметь скролл.
Но скролл не ставиться! 
overflow-x - не отрабатывает!!
Единственный вариант, который я вижу - display: flex; у родителя.
Прошу, помогите справиться с этим.

```css
.currency-table td.name {
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex; /*ТРЫНДЕЦ!!!*/
  overflow: hidden;   /*у оберток выше но можно считать, что у него*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <main>
  <div class="currency-frame">
  <div class="currency-table-wrapper" style="text-align: left;overflow: auto;width: 100%;">
    <table class="currency-table" style="width: 100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th># </th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Market Cap</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Volume(24h)</th>
          <th>Circulating Supply</th>
          <th>Change (24h)</th>
          <th>Price Graph (7d)</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- thead -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="name"><img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png" class="logo-sprite" alt="Bitcoin" width="16" height="16"> Bitcoin Bitcoin Bitcoin</td>
          <td>$109,076,404,206</td>
          <td>$6,342.20</td>
          <td>$4,767,080,028</td>
          <td>17,198,512 BTC</td>
          <td class="fall">-3.47%</td>
          <td class="pic"><img class="sparkline" alt="sparkline" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td class="name"><img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1027.png" class="logo-sprite" alt="Ethereum" width="16" height="16"> Ethereum</td>
          <td>$36,656,267,933</td>
          <td>$362.18</td>
          <td>$1,947,628,100</td>
          <td>101,210,315 ETH</td>
          <td class="grow">3.68%</td>
          <td class="pic"><img class="sparkline" alt="sparkline" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1027.png"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <!-- /tbody -->
    </table>
    <!-- table -->
  </div>
</div>
</main>
  <aside>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae asperiores amet delectus eius, cumque perferendis eveniet ipsa similique ex iure deserunt atque debitis provident, saepe fugiat dignissimos nobis repellendus dolorem.
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Уберите все лишнее и оставьте минимально необходимый код. 2. Чему именно вы пытались присвоить `overflow-x`? Таблице? Так и не отработает, ибо не должно.

Comment: Прошу. Убрала лишний код.
overflow-x присвоен не таблице, а врапперу.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить `flex-direction: column;` к `.wrapper`

```css
.currency-table-wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.currency-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.currency-table th,
.currency-table td {
  padding: 6px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #e1e5ea;
}

.currency-table td.grow {
  color: green;
}

.currency-table td.name {
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 800;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.currency-table td.name img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.currency-table td.pic {
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /*ТРЫНДЕЦ!!!*/
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*у оберток выше но можно считать, что у него*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <main>
    <div class="currency-frame">
      <div class="currency-table-wrapper">
        <table class="currency-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th># </th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Market Cap</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Volume(24h)</th>
              <th>Circulating Supply</th>
              <th>Change (24h)</th>
              <th>Price Graph (7d)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!-- thead -->
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td class="name"><img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1.png" class="logo-sprite" alt="Bitcoin" width="16" height="16"> Bitcoin Bitcoin Bitcoin</td>
              <td>$109,076,404,206</td>
              <td>$6,342.20</td>
              <td>$4,767,080,028</td>
              <td>17,198,512 BTC</td>
              <td class="fall">-3.47%</td>
              <td class="pic"><img class="sparkline" alt="sparkline" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1.png"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td class="name"><img src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/16x16/1027.png" class="logo-sprite" alt="Ethereum" width="16" height="16"> Ethereum</td>
              <td>$36,656,267,933</td>
              <td>$362.18</td>
              <td>$1,947,628,100</td>
              <td>101,210,315 ETH</td>
              <td class="grow">3.68%</td>
              <td class="pic"><img class="sparkline" alt="sparkline" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/sparklines/web/7d/usd/1027.png"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <!-- /tbody -->
        </table>
        <!-- table -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <aside>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae asperiores amet delectus eius, cumque perferendis eveniet ipsa similique ex iure deserunt atque debitis provident, saepe fugiat dignissimos nobis repellendus dolorem.
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не могу сделать враппер колонкой, т.к. это строка в которой лежит майн и сайдебар.((((

Answer (score 0):

ОТВЕТ: Поставить overflow: auto; на обертку.

Answer (score 0):

И все прекрасно работает. Вот (добавил кое-какие габариты, для наглядности и чтобы заставить таблицу быть больше враппера).

```
.currency-table-wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 120px;
}
.currency-table {
  width: 1000px;
}
```